# Why can I use * instead of %*% for matrix in R?

Tags: r

Why can I  use * instead of %*% for matrix in R?

```
a=matrix(1,3,3)
b=matrix(1,3,3)
a*b
```

Comment: Because a and b are actually atomic vectors, so element-wise operators are effective.

Comment: @BondedDust I suspect you're answering a different "why" than the OP intended :-) .

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use * instead of %*%, they give different results.
* is an element wise multiplication and requires your matrices to have the same dimensions.
%*% is actual matrix multiplication.